# переход на страницу сайта

Tags: java, ссылки

Есть сайт moldhome.ru, там чуть ниже, где указаны ряд квартир, ниже каждой квартиры есть кнопки забронировать и подробнее. Сейчас всплывает окно, а мне нужно, чтобы переходило на другую, определенную страницу сайта.

Comment: в вопросе нужно уточнить, какая технология используется, и как должна вычисляться целевая ссылка

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что код не приведён в вопросе, а на сайте вскоре, конечно, изменится, и пользы от вопроса (и ответа) не будет никакой.

Answer (score 1):

Замените `onclick="$('#flat_detail').arcticmodal()"` на диве с кнопкой на что-нибудь вроде `onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'"`

К сожалению, ваш сайт очень неэкономно грузит изображения, что повесило мой Firefox, поэтому более точное решение подсказать физически сложно.

Comment: На такие вопросы не стоит даже отвечать, пока автор не удосужился привести воспроизводимый пример в самом вопросе.

Comment: Олег а что именно вы имеете ввиду "неэкономно грузит изображения"? Тут просто 2 формы установлены это с программы для отелей, их библиотеке js конфликтуют. Их программисты обещали исправить. Можете попробывать другую страницу http://moldhome.ru/odnokomnatnie_kvartiri_posutochno.php